# Действие по истечении времени (проверка каждый день)

Tags: postgresql

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать наблюдение за определенной колонкой?

Нужно сделать следующее: в колонке содержатся даты, нужно, чтоб осуществлялась проверка каждый день. То есть шло сравнение с текущей датой. Если эти значения равны, то осуществлять какое-то действие.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

проще всего такая операция реализовывается на стороне сервера - в cron добавляется ежедневный запуск скрипта myscript.php в какое-то время

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не содержит достаточно информации для ответа. В общем случае, учитывая возможность изменения колонки с датами, требуется периодическое опрашивание базы данных на предмет наличия интересующих событий. Пример на Java: [PgNotificationPoller](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgNotificationPoller).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Попробую написать поподробней. 
Меня в первую очередь интересует, возможно ли такое сделать с помощью БД и с минимальными усилиями.
Просто проблема не стоит того, чтоб разбираться в таком классе или изобретать велосипед.
Я просто думал, может есть команда какая-то, или что-то в этом роде.

В колонке даты. Нужно, чтоб припустим в начале каждого дня срабатывала проверка. Если есть совпадение с актуальной датой, тогда определенные действия.

Comment: Триггер на insert/update?